# Design Ideas for a pricing system that has different prices for different clients

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am attempting to redesign our current product and pricing structure at my company.  Currently, we have products in a products table that has a client's SKU, to make it scan in our app, we associate the SKU to the product's UPC (yes I know they set it up backward and it's labeled as UPC when it is really SKU and vise versa). We then have a table with pricing.
Here is the current ERD.
[image: current erd]

I thought it would be better to implement price books per client, but as I think more about it the amount of data in the price books could get out of hand. We have multiple clients that have multiple price points for the same products. This means the price books pricing table would grow by the number of products every time we add a new client.

Here is the structure I am looking at.
[image: My suggested Structure]
Could anybody suggest a better approach? We are using MySQL, and I do not believe I will be able to move us to another product.

Comment: "price_id"?  Is that linked to anything other than a number?  I recommend putting the value directly in `pricing`.  Also, monetary values should be in `DECIMAL(m,n)`, not `DOUBLE`.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I double-checked my table, and I did set the price as `DECIMAL(8,2)`.  I must not have updated my ERD. Could you elaborate a bit on putting the value directly in pricing?  I can't picture it.

Comment: Are you asking how to do `ALTER TABLE pricing MODIFY price DECIMAL(8.2) etc`, where `etc` is the same as before wrt `[NOT] NULL`. `COMMENT`, etc.

Comment: No.  I'm trying to figure out what you meant by putting the value directly into `pricing`.
Are you suggesting that I drop the `pricebooks_products` and `pricebooks` table and create a `pricing` table? I would assume from there I would have something like `product_id`, `price`, `client_id`, `etc`.  
Now thinking about it, it does make sense.  I would drop tieing pricebooks, and tie it directly with the client.

Comment: Nevermind.  I was misreading your graphics.

Comment: No worries.  I most likely explained poorly.  In sum, I'm attempting to move away from the product and pricing model we are using now because whenever we add a new client, we have to duplicate all the products in the product table.  we have like 6,800 products that we actually work with, but the `products` table we have is over 700,000 rows.

Comment: A diff price for every product for every customer sounds naughty anyway.  A "discount" for selected customers would be a single column in `Customers`.  A "pricing schedule" would be complex, but not require much space -- "Customer x gets 10% discount on payer goods; etc" plus having each product say what type it is (eg, "paper goods".

Comment: I totally agree, but a problem that I have right now is that we do not have a base price for each product.  I've finally convinced the executive team that we need to get a base price for the products, but that is going to take time to get.  This will all be live before we can get that data. Oh.  I think I should mention, that we don't build products to sell to clients, we go to the client to build the products that they have in stock for their displays and/or customers.

Comment: If you are going live soon, then you have the` SELECTs`?  Those should show you the problems in the schema design.